# Recursive function with a one integer parameter

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I am trying to come up with a recursive function which takes a single integer as a starting value. Just a single example is provided and initial value is 9. Example is as follows:

| Input: |
| --- |
| 9 |
| Output: |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 9 |

Each row in the output section represents a return value of a single iteration(2 is the result of f(9)). Question also implies that this output is a result of an algorithm. However, i was not able to find any algorithm that produces this result.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help...

Comment: Integer division by 2? $9 \to 4 \to 2$

Comment: Output is 2 → 4 → 9.

Comment: Then inversed division by 2 sequence :)

Comment: “Question also implies that this output is a result of an algorithm.” What does the question say? There may be a hint in there somewhere?